# Selecting object show nothing in info pane

Tags: python

I am using blender 2.81.

If I change into "Default" view and then manipulate objects then the Info pane shows the Python commands associated with those manipulations.  This is very helpful.

But when I select objects it does not show the equivalent operations.  Specifically I am trying to associate the bones with the mesh and parent them with automatic weights.

It is quite frustrating as I am trying to write a script to automate the export of a rig.

Comment: Please rephrase this as a question.  It is not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Hi! Do you look for mouse select log output? It seems this is missing in blender.

Comment: @RUben yes this is what i am looking for.  normally my procedure is to select bones in pose mode, then switch to object mode and multiselect mesh and bones at same time.  there is no output to show what has happened so i have no idea how to write script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set active object as parent armature deform with Automatic Weights for selected objects, you need to:

1. [select objects include active](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.81/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=select_set#bpy.types.Object.select_set):

   ```
   object.select_set(True)
   ```
2. [set active object](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.81/bpy.types.LayerObjects.html#bpy.types.LayerObjects.active):

   ```
   view_layer.objects.active = object
   ```
3. call operator:

   ```
   bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_AUTO')
   ```

Code example from [scene](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zf2TZF3u3boH90_DsXr0xSF7fKwD941g):

```
import bpy

objects = [
    'Armature',
    'Cylinder',
    'Cylinder.001',
    'Cylinder.002'
    ]

context = bpy.context
view_layer = context.view_layer
scene = context.scene

# select objects include active
for ob in objects:
    scene.objects[ob].select_set(True)

# set active object
view_layer.objects.active = scene.objects[objects[0]]

# call operator
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_AUTO')
```